# upload image with multer is not working on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create image upload API. The code given below is working fine on my local but it does not work on vercel server.Can you help me resolve this problem such that it works on both my local machine and vercel.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import crypto from 'crypto'

export async function POST(request) {
  const data = await request.formData()
  const file = data.get('image')

  if (!file) {
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
  }

  const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer()
  const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes)

  // Generate a unique filename based on the file contents
  const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(buffer).digest('hex')
  const extension = file.name.split('.').pop() // Get file extension
  const uniqueFilename = `${hash}.${extension}`

  // Write the file to the filesystem with the unique filename
  const path = `./public/upload/${uniqueFilename}`
  await writeFile(path, buffer)
  console.log(`Uploaded file saved as: ${path}`)

  return NextResponse.json({ data: `/upload/${uniqueFilename}` })
}
```